# What cable I need for a Western Digital hard drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata

I broke one of my cables from the Hard Drive, but I don’t know what type of cable to buy. The broken cable on one side has the initials “ATA” and the other end is ICT, and I don’t know where to buy it from or what exactly I have to search ti buy the product. The Hard drive is Western Digital  WD10EZEX SATA 6Gb/s PC HA500

Comment: Your drive is this, “Western Digital WD10EZEX SATA” so you need a SATA cable unless you didn’t fully explain the issue clearly here.

Comment: picture of the broken cable &/or the socket on the drive might help

Answer (score 0):

If you broke either the data or power cable it will not work. Replacements are readily available on sites like Amazon or Newegg. You have to connect both a power, and data cable to your hard drive. The power cable you buy will be dependent on what connections your power supply has. Some power supplies are full-modular (You must connect *all* cables to the PSU manually), semi-modular (Some expansion ports/slots are available where usually the main motherboard power cable is already attached), or non-modular (no expansion ports/slots, cables are attached to the PSU during manufacturing).

**SATA data cable looks like this:**
[image]

**SATA power connector looks like this:**

[image]

SATA Wiki page: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA